# ASP.NET Core RC2 with Entity Framework Core RC 2 migrations

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've a very simple ASP.NET Core RC2 application which uses Identity and EF Core RC2 and I'm seeding the database with some user account. When I was developing the same application in RC1, I write all of my code and there is no database exists in SQL Server. I run the application and my database, schema and the data that I was seeding becomes available without migrations with Code first approach.

If I try the same application in ASP.NET Core RC2 and EF Core RC2, I get the exception as *failed to establish the connection with the database.*, if I apply migrations, it works and seed the data successfully. I've to create the database first and apply the migrations in order to get the job done.

The questions is that **Is migration becomes necessary in EF Core RC2**?

If yes, then **How do I make migrations in an Azure SQL instance running production without using Visual Studio publish tools in EF Core RC2.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about something like `dbContext.Database.Migrate()` during application startup ?

Comment: Was not that `dbcontext.Database.ApplyMigrations()` before? If yes, how do I apply this in ASP.NET Core at runtime?